# Why saying "so long an absence" instead of "a so long absence"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

I have usually seen "a + adj + noun" instead of "adj + a + noun". In the sentence below, why the speaker used the latter? Did he want to transfer a special meaning e.g. emphasizing on the adjective, in this case the very long period that no one had expected? The situation was that the speaker went to the US for a meeting and suddenly he had to have an operation and stay a while in a hospital.

> It's grand to be home again after **so long an absence**. [The Crown]

Comment: It wasn't my down-vote, but you may want to add more detail to your question to attract some up-votes. There are some examples of questions with a good amount of detail in [this answer to the Details, Please post on meta](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4584/9161).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of no *syntactical* reason why it would be wrong.

We can say all of these:

> ✔ An extended absence.
>   ✔ A long absence.
>   ✔ So long an absence.
>   ✔ An absence so long.

*So long* is acting as an adjective, and we can put adjectives in front of and behind nouns.

So, why should the following be wrong?

> ✘ (?) A so long absence.

This seems simply like one of those situations where it sounds wrong "because it sounds wrong" situations.

Even though I can think of no logical reason for the phrase to be wrong, it's just not used idiomatically.